# Duplicate class in classes.jar on build project after update of Android Studio

Tags: java, android, libraries

I have recently update Android Studio to the latest version and since I have been facing problem with the libraries connecting to it.

The latest problem faced is the following:

[image]

```
Cause 1: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class     com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzsr found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzss found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzst found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzsu found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzsv found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcu found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcv found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcw found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcx found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcy found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdw found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.await(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:56)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicateClassesDelegate.run(CheckDuplicateClassesDelegate.kt:71)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicateClassesTask.taskAction(CheckDuplicateClassesTask.kt:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:702)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:669)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:404)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:393)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:376)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:213)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzsr found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzss found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzst found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzsu found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzsv found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcu found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcv found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcw found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcx found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcy found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdw found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable.run(CheckDuplicateClassesDelegate.kt:132)
at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:40)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalInterruptibleAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:361)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1001)
... 99 more
```

Find below the **app Gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.packageName"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable "ResourceType"
    }
}

ext {
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "4.2.0"
}


dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/icu4j-4_4_2_2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jsoup-1.6.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    implementation files('libs/zip4j_1.2.6.jar')

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar')     {
        transitive = true;
    }

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.38.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1'

    implementation project(':pdflibrary')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:16.0.1'   
}
```

Find below the **pdf Library Gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

Find below the **Project Gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I have checked the following questions but no suggestion would work: 
[Android Studio: Resolving Duplicate Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990054/android-studio-resolving-duplicate-classes)

This could be a duplicate question of the following:
[61 Duplicate classes in classes.jar, WHERE is classes.jar located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977552/61-duplicate-classes-in-classes-jar-where-is-classes-jar-located). But unfortunately it was not answered. I hope it would attract attention to the issue.

Comment: Looks like duplicate classes of com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement from your play services and firebase package is getting included in the generated classes.jar. 
Try `./gradlew app:dependencies` and see from which specific libraries this is getting included.

Comment: try to remove sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        } from pdf Library Gradle

Comment: @MohammadSommakia Thank for your contribution, I just need to mention that it's a wrong practice to remove the source sets for it will disable the ability to loadLibrary from system and access the libraries in jni folder

Comment: I was experiencing the same problem and I know this is not a real solution to underlying problem but, I managed to compile by upgrading my inclusion of all `com.google.android.gms` libraries to version `17.0.0`. So for example: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0`

Answer (score 8):

I have faced same issue. after add firebase libray my issue was solved. so I hope It will help you.

```
 api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
```

Comment: are  you mean ``implementation``?

Comment: Adding this line to my dependencies in build.gradle solved my issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**I was using in old version of libraries I just convert it to the following **

```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.1'
```

**also make sure you add the following in your gradle.bulid**

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

**check this if not then also don't forget to add this code**

```
    compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In build.grandle type multiDexEnabled true in buildTypes:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        multiDexEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, the error was quite similar but different classes

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzb found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0)
```

I stumbled on [this](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation/issues/229) react-native issues thread where I found a fix. I simply included

```
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+") {
    force = true
}
```

the plus allows com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+ to get upgraded and use the latest version, I think some other dependency relies solely on it because I previously didn't have any google SDK or firebase lib in my project.

Comment: First I like to mention that this works fine, but  the attribute force = true is deprecated. Second, according to google developer's site . . . . "Don't use the combined play-services target. It brings in dozens of libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses." There fore, the solution for this is that use the latest version specifically. implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.4.0'   . . . . https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 0):

There tends to be class conflicts if versions of play-services-places, play-services-maps, and play-services-location don't match up. For example, your `app/build.gradle` file should look like this:

```
dependencies{
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'    
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for my case was different but maybe could help

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar'])
implementation(name:'HERE-sdk', ext:'aar')
```

problem was i was implementing same class of.aar so i received duplicate class warnings

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])