# Build Failed - Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED

Tags: javascript, android

I was using Unity ads in my Android Studio Java application, then I wanted to migrate Appodeal, Appodeal supports Androidx, I tried to make my application androidx, I edited many files, but I can't get past this error.
Can you help me. Where am I doing wrong?

**Project Build.Grandle**

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'}

        maven {
            url "https://artifactory.appodeal.com/appodeal"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Module Build.Grandle**

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {

    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 15
        versionName '15'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    ndkVersion '23.0.7123448 rc1'
    buildToolsVersion '31.0.0 rc1'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.guilhe:circular-progress-view:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads:sdk:2.11.0.+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
   // implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.3'






}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Build Failed**

```html
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbj found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbk found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbl found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbm found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbn found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbo found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbp found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbq found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbr found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbs found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzi found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzir found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzit found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zziu found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zziv found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zziw found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzix found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zziy found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zziz found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzj found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzja found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjb found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjc found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjd found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzje found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjf found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjg found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjh found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzji found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjj found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjk found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjl found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjm found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjn found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjo found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjp found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjq found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjr found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjs found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjt found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzju found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjv found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjw found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjx found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjy found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzjz found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzka found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzkb found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzkc found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzkd found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzke found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzkf found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzkg found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzkh found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzki found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzkj found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzkk found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzkl found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzkm found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfh found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgl found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgm found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgn found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgo found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgp found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgq found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhs found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhx found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate class in classes.jar on build project after update of Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574910/duplicate-class-in-classes-jar-on-build-project-after-update-of-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like something is wrong with your Gradle,

try the steps in this similar answer:

Go to gradle.properties(project properties)

Add
android.enableJetifier=true

And also most of time android.useAndroidX=true is present.Check your gradle.properties(Project Properties) and if it does not exist then add
android.useAndroidX=true

Quote from that thread: If you want to use androidx-namespaced libraries in a new project, you need to set the compile SDK to Android 9.0 (API level 28) or higher and set both of the mentioned Android Gradle plugin flags to true.

android.useAndroidX: When this flag is set to true, the Android plugin uses the appropriate AndroidX library instead of a Support Library. The flag is false by default if it is not specified.

android.enableJetifier: When this flag is set to true, the Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX dependencies by rewriting their binaries. The flag is false by default if it is not specified.

[Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. Ionic4 Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716047/execution-failed-for-task-appcheckdebugduplicateclasses-ionic4-android)